# How does the proxy contract gets the storage variables of Implementation contract?

Tags: storage, proxy-contracts, upgrading, contract-upgrading

I understand that proxies use delegatecall to execute the logic contract's function with its own storage.

But what happens when we define any storage variables in the logic contract as well as initialize it at the same time.

How does the proxy get that value from the variable? For example, I am sharing the compound governance code.

This is the [implementation](https://github.com/compound-finance/compound-governance/blob/main/contracts/GovernorBravoDelegate.sol) contract, notice the variables are initialized. After deploying how does the storage of proxy gets updated with the exact values???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those variables are marked as **`constant`**, which means they are part of the bytecode and are not stored in contract storage. Sometimes, you may see some variables are **`immutable`**. In that case, they are also part of the bytecode. The values for those types of variables, are initialized during the deployment in the constructor and can't be reassigned later.

Comment: Got it, thanks.